# AndroidTests stopped building after adding androidx.fragment:fragment-testing dependency

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, androidx-test

After I have added `fragment-testing` dependency to my project:

```
    // Testing dependencies
    espressoVersion = '3.2.0-beta01'
    testCoreVersion = '1.1.0'
    runnerVersion = '1.1.0'
    extJunitVersion = '1.1.0'
    testRulesVersion = '1.1.0'
    fragmentVersion = '1.1.0-alpha09'
    orchestratorVersion = '1.1.0'
    uiAutomatorVersion = '2.2.0'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
    mockitoVersion = '2.7.22'
    robolectricVersion = '4.2.1'
    liveDataTestingVersion = '1.1.0'
    androidArchCoreTestingVersion = '2.0.0'

androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion")
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:$rootProject.ext.testCoreVersion"
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:runner:$rootProject.ext.runnerVersion")
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.ext.extJunitVersion"
androidTestUtil ("androidx.test:orchestrator:$rootProject.ext.orchestratorVersion")
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion")
implementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$rootProject.ext.espressoVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:$rootProject.ext.uiAutomatorVersion"
testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.ext.junitVersion"
androidTestImplementation("androidx.test:rules:$rootProject.ext.testRulesVersion")
// required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
// required if you want to use Mockito for Android tests
androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:$rootProject.ext.mockitoVersion"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$rootProject.ext.robolectricVersion"
testImplementation "org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:$rootProject.ext.robolectricVersion"
// LiveData Testing utility
testImplementation "com.jraska.livedata:testing:$rootProject.ext.liveDataTestingVersion"
testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.ext.androidArchCoreTestingVersion"
// Once https://issuetracker.google.com/127986458 is fixed this can be testImplementation
implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$rootProject.ext.fragmentVersion")
```

when I try to build the `androidTests` it fails:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':MyApp:mergeEsmartliveDebugAndroidTestResources'.

> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':MyApp:esmartliveDebugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve androidx.test:core:1.1.0.
>        Required by:
>            project :MyApp
>            project :MyApp > androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0
>            project :MyApp > androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha09
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Constraint path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: esmartliveDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha09' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>
> Could not resolve androidx.test:core:{strictly 1.1.0}.
>        Required by:
>            project :MyApp
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Constraint path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: esmartliveDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha09' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>
> Could not resolve androidx.test:monitor:1.1.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :MyApp > androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.1'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0-beta01'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0-beta01'
>
> Could not resolve androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01.
>        Required by:
>            project :MyApp > androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0-beta01
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:core' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Constraint path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:{strictly 1.1.0}' because of the following reason: esmartliveDebugRuntimeClasspath uses version 1.1.0
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-alpha09' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.1.0'
>
> Could not resolve androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0-beta01.
>        Required by:
>            project :MyApp > androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01
>            project :MyApp > androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01
>   Cannot find a version of 'androidx.test:monitor' that satisfies the version constraints: 
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.1.1'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0-beta01'
>              Dependency path 'MyApp:unspecified' --> 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0-beta01' --> 'androidx.test:monitor:1.2.0-beta01'

Not sure how to handle this kind of conflicts... Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a quick solution:

```
implementation ("androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:1.1.0-beta01", {         
   exclude group: 'androidx.test', module: 'core'
})
```

Comment: I get a compilation error on gradle with this. Is this syntax really correct?

Comment: @Rod you can probably ask [here](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/294#issuecomment-506994394) or [here](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix/issues/5217)

Comment: Thanks for the kind response Elroid. I ended up figuring out the right syntax too.
Now, about the problem in question, including this in gradle makes my fragment unit tests to fail with the following error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/test/core/app/ActivityScenario$ActivityAction`

Comment: As stated, it's a _quick_ solution. If you really need that module I'm afraid you're gonna have to find another answer.

Comment: What is the solution exactly?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky excluding the conflicting `core` module

Comment: This comes up again in 2022 because androidx.test just bumped from 1.4.0 to 1.5.0 and fragment-testing requires 1.4.0 "strictly"